# ironpython run error : mainWindow has no attribute

Tags: wpf, ironpython

`Ironpython can't excute exist button_click event?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WPF IronPython Integration" Height="300" Width="400">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="PythonCodeBox" Height="150" Width="360" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20"/>
        <Button x:Name="ExecuteButton" Content="Execute" Width="100" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20" Click="OnExecuteButtonClick"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="OutputTextBlock" Width="360" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ScriptEngine _pythonEngine;

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            OutputTextBlock.Text = "Test from C#";

            _pythonEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
        }

        private void OnExecuteButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var pythonCode = PythonCodeBox.Text;
                var scope = _pythonEngine.CreateScope();

                // Pass the MainWindow instance to the Python script
                scope.SetVariable("mainWindow", this);

                var result = _pythonEngine.Execute(pythonCode, scope);
                OutputTextBlock.Text = result?.ToString() ?? "No output";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

ironpython input :

```
mainWindow.OutputTextBlock.Text = "This text is set from IronPython!"
```

Error. MainWindow object has no attribute"OutputTextBlock'

how to deal with this error?  i want to use ironpython to modify existing  OutputTextBlock content`

Comment: Straight out the box, Iron python has no concept of what Wpf is, let alone UI controls. I think you would need to load the Wpf assemblies into ironpython. It's quite a nuisance to do anything substantial with UI using it. What are you trying to achieve using iron python?